# GStreamer compilation error on Mac OS-X 64 bit

Tags: gstreamer

I have tried to compile and link Gstreamer library to a run the first tutorial but unfortunately, I get a bunch of errors. The errors are:

> Can't write output file: basictutorial for architecture x86_64
>   gst-plugin-scanner:Failed to load plugin '/Library/GStreamer/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so': dlopen(/Library/GStreamer/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so, 2): no suitable image found.
>
> Did find:
>   /Library/GStreamer/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

The command i used in gstreamer is

```
gcc -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers basic-tutorial-1.c -o basictutorial -framework GStreamer
```

Comment: Tilak, by any change did u find answer? if so, would you mind sharing? Thanks.